# Can we make [livedata] = [android-livedata] = [android-architecture-livedata]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Currently these three tags are used for [**`Android LiveData`**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

1. [android-architecture-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-livedata)

   Use this tag for questions related to the LiveData Architecture Component API
2. [android-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-livedata)

   Android LiveData holds the value and allow it to observe changes and also respects lifecycle of the app components.
3. While the [livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/livedata) tag has no usage guidance

As per my opinion we need to merge these three tags, because these all tags are used for questions related to **Android architecture livedata**.

Questions tagged [android-architecture-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-livedata) 134 questions

Questions tagged [android-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-livedata) 621 questions

Questions tagged [livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/livedata) 36 questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were 5 questions in [livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/livedata) which did not have the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag. Went through all of them to make sure that they are related to Android Livedata, which they were.

I added [livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/livedata) and [android-architecture-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-livedata) as synonyms of [android-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-livedata), as that tag had almost 4 times the number of questions of the other two tags combined. The situation now is:

[android-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-livedata) × 688 <- [livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/livedata) × 49
[android-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-livedata) × 688 <- [android-architecture-livedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-architecture-livedata) × 146